# docker : where to find the docker-compose.yml and the physical image of the machine

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker , sorry in advance if my questions have a feeling of 'déja-vu'

I've started this tutorial, which I followed sequentially

https://realpython.com/blog/python/dockerizing-flask-with-compose-and-machine-from-localhost-to-the-cloud/

2 questions pop up after setting up a new machine :

1) when typing `docker-machine ls` , I can see this

```
dev       -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376
```

Where is the physical file on my machine

2) I'm looking for this file `docker-compose.yml` but I cannot find it ...

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `docker-machine ls` is giving the ip of your virtual box, there isn't any physical file yet. You need to run the containers where you will be getting the physical files.
2. `docker-compose.yml` file you have to create.